# Override toString() method to remove Square brackets? []

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring, square-bracket

**EDIT**

---

I changed toString method like this and now it works.

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    Mylist.forEach((a) -> {
        System.out.print(a+" ");
    });

     return "";
}
```

There is a better way to do it?

Thank you for the answer.

**END EDIT**

---

I'm learning java, and I'm playing with ArrayList.

I wrote this code and i don't know how to Override toString() method to remove Square brackets.

I'm new to Java, so can you show me a way to do it please?

Thank you.

```
package ExampleCollections;

import java.util.*;

public class ExampleCollections {

  public ArrayList Mylist;

  public ExampleCollections(ArrayList Mylist) {

      Mylist.add("A");
      Mylist.add("Z");
      Mylist.add("C");
      Mylist.add("T");
      Mylist.add("D");

      this.Mylist=Mylist;
  }


  public void MakeSort(){
      Collections.sort(Mylist);
      System.out.println(this);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
        //How can i remove square brackets??
        return String.format("Values= "+Mylist);
  }




  public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList letters = new ArrayList();

      ExampleCollections e = new ExampleCollections(letters);

      System.out.println(e);

      e.MakeSort();

    }
}
```

As result i get:

```
Values= [A, Z, C, T, D]
Values= [A, C, D, T, Z]
```

How can i override the toString() method to remove the [] from the result?
Thank you.

Comment: [This has been asked before a time or two](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+remove+square+brackets+arraylist#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+remove+square+brackets+arraylist+tostring). Please consider searching first.

Comment: I've edited my question to show a possible solution looking at the same answers to this similar question, thank you.

Comment: You're code is confused as there is no business for `System.out.print(...)` within a `toString()` method. Remember that this method's reason for existing is solely to create and return a String, not to print anything. The printing should be all left to the code that calls this method.

Comment: `"I changed toString method like this and now it works."` ?? No. It certainly doesn't work. Again, you want to build and return a String. Read the duplicates that I've linked to as they show examples of good workable code.